# How to access data using web services in android from any server host

Tags: android, ipv6, ipv4

I get Some Issues when I call Webservice using **HttpURLConnection**.
After searching i need to call Webservice and send request through ipv6 or ipv4 to server, I got ipv4 or ipv6 but I don't know how to send request using ipv6 or ipv4 here is my code :

```
java.net.URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(URL);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(50000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(50000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(50000);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d("Util", "Response Code" + URL + " - " + responseCode);
        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            Log.d("Util", "If" + responseCode);
            String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response += line;
            }
        } else if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CLIENT_TIMEOUT) {
            Log.d("Util", "TimeOut" + responseCode);
            response = "";
        }
        Log.d("jai", "response :" + response);

        if (response == null || response == "" || response.equals("")) {
            Log.d("jai", "response : null" + response);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
```

Comment: what does the logcat say! about the error ! please post your logcat in the question thnx

Comment: there is no error beacause i have no idea how set ipv6 or ipv4

Comment: do read about Volley or retrofit please. they are highly advanced ways to get data from webservices

Comment: in read that but i want send requets through ipv6 or ipv4 i don't how to do

Comment: so you are saying that you need to get some data from server but that server requires your mobile Ipaddress or so!    but all servers already know that they are being pinged by what IP address!

please make me clear on that

Comment: help me to understand more so that I could come up with the solution! for you! brother

Comment: i'm sending request to server but my php side they want to get request throught either ipv6 or ipv4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170368/discussion-between-sanjay-and-rizwan-atta).